# curl several files and save output in one file

Tags: bash, curl

I am using `curl` to grab the HTML of a website. I want to only grab the first 20 lines, and save this in an external file. I need to grab about 10 URLs, and want to save all of them in the same file. Preferably with the URL of each file above the results. What I came up with is:

`curl http://example.com/url1 | head -20 && curl http://example.com/url2 | head -20 > exportfile`

However, this yields two issues:

- This only saves the latest page (and if I put > exportfile after every statement, it overvwrites the file
- This does not save the actual command in the file

Any way to make this work as I intend?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could save all your URLs in a file (say `urls.txt`, one per line), then loop over them in your script:

```
#! /bin/bash

# optional, clean up before starting
rm exportfile

while read url ; do
   echo "URL: $url"       >> exportfile
   curl "$url" | head -20 >> exportfile
done < urls.txt
```

One of the important things is using `>>` to append. `>` overwrites.

Comment: Great, works as a charm!

Answer (score 2):

Try this (bash):

```
{ curl http://example.com/url1 | head -20 \
  && curl http://example.com/url2 | head -20; } > exportfile
```

Comment: Thanks, works fine, but it does not put the URL at the top of the output.